# What does g_signal_connect_swapped() do?

Tags: signals, gtk, gobject

According to GObject reference

> g_signal_connect_swapped(instance, detailed_signal, c_handler, data); connects a GCallback function to a signal for a particular object. The instance on which the signal is emitted and data will be swapped when calling the handler.

I don't quite get what this means. Does this mean that the `data` will point to the object pointed to by`instance` and `instance` will point to the object that was pointed to by `data` or am I making a mistake here?

If former is the case then what is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You understand correctly.

This allows you to do tricks like the following: You have a button (let's call it `button`), that is supposed to hide another widget (let's call it `textview`) when pressed.

You can then do

```
g_signal_connect_swapped(button, 'clicked', G_CALLBACK(gtk_widget_hide), textview);
```

to achieve that. When the button is pressed, it generates the 'clicked' signal, and the callback is called with `textview` as the first argument, and `button` as the second. In this case the callback is `gtk_widget_hide()` which only takes one argument, so the second argument is ignored, because that's the way the C calling convention works.

It's the same as the following, but shorter.

```
static void
on_button_clicked(GtkButton *button, GtkWidget *textview)
{
    gtk_widget_hide(textview);
}

...elsewhere...

    g_signal_connect(button, 'clicked', G_CALLBACK(on_button_clicked), textview);
```

Basically it saves you from having to write an extra function if you hand-code your interface. Of course, there may be some far more practical use that I've never understood.

Comment: It's also good for generally making events from children invoke handlers with `self` as the first argument, e.g.: `g_signal_connect_swapped (self->some_internal_child, "button-press-event", (GCallback)my_mouse_handler, self)`. Doing that without `swapped` would mean having an ugly signature on the receiving side with a 1st argument that probably isn't interesting in the majority of cases, and which you can often get from `self->` anyway. Or at least that's how I've made use of this so far...