# g_signal_connect & g_signal_connect_swapped

Tags: c, gtk

I am using this [tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html) for `GTK` learning. The second example in that link uses the two functions: `g_signal_connect` and `g_signal_connect_swapped`. I don't see any differences in the calling of the two functions, but I found the following in the `gsignal.h` (this can also be found [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect-swapped)):

```
    For example, this allows the shorter code:
    |[<!-- language="C" -->
    g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked",
                              (GCallback) gtk_widget_hide, other_widget);
    ]|

    Rather than the cumbersome:
    |[<!-- language="C" -->
    static void
    button_clicked_cb (GtkButton *button, GtkWidget *other_widget)
    {
        gtk_widget_hide (other_widget);
    }

    …

    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked",
                      (GCallback) button_clicked_cb, other_widget);
    ]|
```

When I compile the code with the `g_signal_connect_swapped` replaced with `g_signal_connect`, the program will not work properly; however, if I do the opposite thing, it still works. Can anyone tell me what is the differences between the two functions? Also, if confusion is not wanted, is it better to always use `g_signal_connect_swapped` instead of the other?

***EDIT:*** The code for the "second example":

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>

    static void
    print_hello (GtkWidget *widget,
                 gpointer   data)
    {
      g_print ("Hello World\n");
    }

    static void
    activate (GtkApplication *app,
              gpointer        user_data)
    {
      GtkWidget *window;
      GtkWidget *button;
      GtkWidget *button_box;

      window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
      gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
      gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

      button_box = gtk_button_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
      gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box);

      button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");
      g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);
      g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);
      gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button_box), button);

      gtk_widget_show_all (window);
    }

    int
    main (int    argc,
          char **argv)
    {
      GtkApplication *app;
      int status;

      app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
      g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
      status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
      g_object_unref (app);

      return status;
    }
```

Comment: "The program will not work properly..." Can you explain what you expected to see and what you actually saw?

Comment: Well, originally, it is designed to close the window and also print a string "Hello World" on the terminal. If I changed the functions, the button will disappear, but the window is not closed

Comment: So according to the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171724/what-does-g-signal-connect-swapped-do), is that the `g_signal_connect_swapped` passes the last parameter to the callback function? Like in that post, it passes the `textview` as parameter to `gtk_widget_hide()`?